# Draw.io in Confluence: For multiple overlayed workflows button to focus on different workflows

Tags: app.diagrams.net, confluence

Draw.io (Draw.io plugin v 6.3.4.1) in Confluence: 
I am making a diagram that shows multiple workflows, to be displayed in confluence. I would like a way, say with buttons, to help viewer focus on different workflows. I know I could keep different workflows in different layers. How do I now create configurations of selected layers and tie that to buttons in draw.io/confluence?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with layer. You may know the layer functionality in MS Visio, also draw.io provide that feature to implement a ton of information in one diagram and differ them between multiple view levels. The user has the possibility to check and uncheck layers for different information views.

You´ll find that in the global menu under "view" and then the third menu "layer".

Please check that out.